# Trying to write my own constraint based layout engine with user overrides

Tags: layout, autolayout, constraint-programming

I'm looking to build my own layout engine where it lays out elements automatically but also allows for a user to override these values (e.g. a more aesthetic layout) if the auto layout if not sufficient.

That being said, I've found libraries like D3 and Cola.js but I cannot find resources/tutorials in teaching these techniques to write your own layout engine.

Here's a simple example from Cola.js (https://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/examples/smallgroups.html) for reference.